# What's the different between a constructor & method in Python?

Tags: python, methods, constructor

Can anyone simply explain the difference between constructors and methods in Python

Comment: It is pretty the same difference as in any other object-oriented prgramming language: the constructor is a special method, it is just invoked differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class is instantiated, its `__init__` method is called to initialize the class instance.  Memory is allocated for the class instance, `__init__` is called, and the new class is returned.  `__init__` is the constructor for the class.  For example:

```
c = MyClass(123)
```

When `__init__` is called, the first argument, `self`, is bound to the new class instance, and the second argument is `123`.

An ordinary method operates on an existing class instance:

```
c.myMethod(456)
```

In this case, the first argument, `self`, is bound to `c`, which is an existing class instance, and the second argument is `456`.

In most ways `__init__` is like any other method of the class, except it is implicitly called when a new class instance is created.